# How do I update app installed from 3rd-party with Google Play Store's version?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

I want to update my WhatsApp to be able to use the calling feature. I've used a third party app to update WhatsApp till now. How do I update from Play Store, or will it only happen automatically and not manually?

Answer (score 1):

The call feature is available in `WhatsApp-2.12.5`.

The Google Play Store should show you the latest version (If `Notification Checked`)

> How do I update from Play Store, or will it only happen automatically
>   and not manually?

This is only available, when the below option is enabled: if this option is disable, you need to download manually.

[image]

As you can see in above option, if there is an update it will be shown in a notification.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I update from Play Store?

1. Open your Play Store;
2. From the left edge of screen do a left to right swipe to access Play Store Menu;
3. Select **My Apps** - it will open a list of all apps installed from Play Store;
4. Find Whatsapp Messnger, select Whatsapp Messenger and you will be presented with a page of Whatsapp;
5. Otherwise, after "**Step 1.**", type in Search Bar **Whatsapp**, enter and select "Whatsapp messenger" from the list.
6. From there you can select **Update** option if it is available.

> Will it only happen automatically and not manually?

On that Whatsapp page, press Context menu key (usually the hardware key left to Home key in the bottom panel of your phone), and check **Auto-Update** option. Otherwise, you can access Play Store menu, select **Settings -> Auto-update Apps** option and choose update option relevant to you.

---

#### **Note**:

> I've used a third party app to update WhatsApp till now.

It is recommended by Google and many security vendors to not to use anything other than Play Store to install or update any app. Be cautioned about privacy and security issue when you use third-party clients.

**Edit**: I've incorporated `Rohit Kabdwal's` points here in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upper Points are correctly given to update your WhatsApp application from play store, but if you want to enable the voice calling feature in your application then,

- Find one person who already has the WhatsApp calling feature enabled in his/her application.
- Ask that person to call you through his/her WhatsApp Voice calling feature.
- Then receive that call (Note: your phone should be connected to the internet to receive the call)
- When you end the call, you will see three different tabs in your WhatsApp application.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you mentioned you would like to update the app from the Google Play Store, however when I checked if an update was available using the methods in the other answers, the Play Store said that my app was up to date.

**With this in mind**, if you navigate to the [download page of the WhatsApp website](https://www.whatsapp.com/android/), it will allow you to download the latest .apk which you can install manually.